# Multiple JOINS in SQL with dataset

Tags: sql, join, left-join

I have 3 tables that I need to JOIN in SQL.

Table A: Contains Employee ID
Table B: Contains Employee ID AND fica number
Table C: Contains fica number

Table A and B both contain an employee ID column. Table B and C both contain a column that has an employee's fica number. I need to find out all of the employees that are present in table C but not in table A. I wanted to do that by joining the fica number from table A and table A, then from there I was going to match up the employee ID that correlates to the fica number and try and JOIN that with table A. I try writing the syntax like this:

```
select distinct(a.employee_id), c.FICA_NBR, b.first_name, b.last_name from benefit A
join B on b.employee_id = a.employee_id
left join C on c.FICA_NBR = b.FICA_NBR
where c.FICA_NBR IS NULL
order by a.employee_id;
```

How would I go about editing this syntax?

Comment: All of these tables have columns that relate to a specific employee, however table A refers to them by employee ID and table C refers to them by fica_nbr. Table B is the middle man in this case and I want to be able to correlate the fica_nbr to the employee id. I can do that in table B, but the problem is I need to find all of the employees that are in table C that are NOT in table A, that is where I am havng issues

Comment: Table C is a census, and I am trying to find people that are active in the census that are not present in column A

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct a.employee_id, c.FICA_NBR, b.first_name, b.last_name from C 
join B on  c.FICA_NBR = b.FICA_NBR   
left join  benefit A on b.employee_id = a.employee_id
where A.employee_id IS NULL
order by a.employee_id;
```

The above code should help you achieve the goal since your condition is data is not present in table a, then its primary key should be null.
Hope I answered your question

Comment: This worked. Thanks! I was a couple steps off.